# Is it possible to use exec to remote another pc in tcl

Tags: tcl, psexec, netsh

I want to remote another pc to connect/disconnect wifi through psexec & netsh command

In .bat file I can remote by "psexec" command:

```
psexec \\ip -u admin -p password cmd.exe
```

I have tried several function in tcl such as follows

```
exec cmd.exe /psexec \\ip -u admin -p password cmd.exe
```

But it didn't work. It shows that psexec is not recognized as internal or external program.

Is it possible to solve in this method, or  there is anotherway to approach same purpose, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to psexec directly without cmd.exe if psexec is a proper executable

Comment: such like directly use   " psexec \\ip -u admin -p password cmd.exe /c argv  "??

Comment: `exec psexec ...` instead of `exec cmd.exe psexec ...`

Comment: Also, you'll need to quote or escape the backslashes for your ip address: `{\\ip}` or `\\\\ip`

Comment: thanks a lot guys, but here is another thing. I can maintain the control of the WIFI connect/disconnect , but after i connect /disconnect the interface then it exit quickly, what i mean is : the rest of the code haven't done but it exit.  how can i let it return to finish the rest of the code. thanks!